# EMC-branded DS24-M2 McData: Where get and what firmware?

Tags: fibre-channel, emc

I (will) get a EMC Symmetrix DS24-M2 FC Switch which is a branded McData 4500. I'm unsure how/if it's possible to update the box to the latest firmware without an official service contract anymore. (Officialy you can only get FW from EMC via valid contract,but its for fun use...)

With Brocade switches, since they don't allow OEM modification on their firmware, you can flash  FabOS images for let's say HP or IBM branded boxes that are freely downloadable.

Does anyone know whether EMC did just slap their sticker on the McData's or modified the FW so it only accepts EMC-branded MEOS?

Answer (score 1):

EMC simply puts a sticker on the switch, you're fine getting code from McData/Brocade directly or EMC.

Latest code for it appears to be EOS 09.09.09 from January 2011.  Depending on what code you're running you may need to go through some additional code revs to get up there.

Your big concern is to make sure you retain any license keys applied to the switch so they continue to go up through the versions of code.

Contact me directly and I can provide you a link to grab the code.

Comment: Great, so this confirms what I hoped (no EMC FW branding). - I may contact you once I get these switches in couple of days. Unlike with Fabric OS, it seems confirmed that M-EOS is more prone to lose installed license keys, so thanks for pointng that out.